# How to filter dynamically instead of using if-else statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a redux hook responsible for server data that I want to pass into a set state after filtering it..
But with a dynamic condition.

```
// states 
const [drilledData, setDrilledData] = useState([])
```

Current Code:

```
const drillDownData = (seriesIndex, dataPointIndex) => {
    // here series index could be from 1-80 in that order
    // dataPointIndex is a number and item.dataSet is also a number
    // Refactor this code to remove if-else statements to something better

    if (seriesIndex === 0) {
      const filteredData = coscoData.filter((item) => item.dataSet === dataPointIndex)
      setDrilledData(filteredData[0].shipments)
    } else if (seriesIndex === 1) {
      const filteredData = hapagData.filter((item) => item.dataSet === dataPointIndex)
      setDrilledData(filteredData[0].shipments)
    } else if (seriesIndex === 2) {
      const filteredData = maerskData.filter((item) => item.dataSet === dataPointIndex)
      setDrilledData(filteredData[0].shipments)
    } else if (seriesIndex === 3) {
      const filteredData = othersData.filter((item) => item.dataSet === dataPointIndex)
      setDrilledData(filteredData[0].shipments)
    } else {
      setDrilledData([])
    }
    return null
  }
```

Currently, the if-else statement is straightforward and works fine. But I have to repeat that if else statement 80 times. because I have to filter the data and  with respect to series index and dataPointIndex and its related dataSet to set them conditionally

like data example

```
aclData,
admiralLineData,
anlData,
aplData,
arkasData,
```

data inside them is like that but dataSet can b more than one. so I'm using the filter to pick up matching dataSet to the pointIndex.

```
aclData = ['dataSet': 1, 'shipments' : [...{more objects}]]
```

So, I want to make that if else statement dynamic so I don't have to write up to 80 times to cover all the dataSets. How I can do that. ? I don't need to you refactor all code accurately, any idea or pseudo code will also be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Is the relationship between the index number and the relevant data set static?
If so, could you create a util object that records those relationships and then use that to dynamically call the data set that you are trying to use? It would be less clunky than a giant if else (or switch statement), and reusable.

If the pattern for the above suggestion is too tricky to implement, a switch statement that calls a helper function, can at least reduce your code:

```
const filterMyData = (pertinentData, dataIndex) => {
    const filteredData = pertinentData.filter((item) => item.dataSet === 
    dataIndex)
    setDrilledData(filteredData[0].shipments)
}
```

and then

```
  switch (seriesIndex) {
     case 0:
       filterMyData(coscoData, dataToPointIndex);
       break;
     case 1:
       filterMyData(hapagData, dataToPointIndex);
       break;
     ....
  }
```

Comment: seriesIndex is static, it won't change. but dataToPointIndex is not static.

Comment: I updated the code above. Theoretically if dataToPointIndex is in the same scope as the helper function, you can just use it, but if it is not, I updated the code to take that as a parameter.